# Clean up datasheet with 70000 rows- Delete all lines starting with "A" or "="

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Is there a way to program that a all rows starting with "A" must be deleted?
I am working with a sheet with 70000 rows and need to do a clean up before I can use any formulas- because it takes forever when the formulas are added.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using PowerShell Script. A quick Google brought me [this page](https://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/06/22/how-can-i-delete-specified-rows-in-an-excel-spreadsheet.aspx?Redirected=true) of MSFT Scripting Guys' blog post.

A snippet from that post is,

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Scripts\Test.xls")

i = 1

Do Until objExcel.Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
    If objExcel.Cells(i, 1).Value = "delete" Then
        Set objRange = objExcel.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow
        objRange.Delete
        i = i - 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

You still need to modify this script based on your need but it should give you idea.